# What will be the launch and landing sites for Orion?

Tags: launch-site, landing, orion-spacecraft

There is [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/could-the-space-shuttle-have-landed-on-any-long-runway-other-than-those-speciall) that is very interesting. But it made me wonder about upcoming systems.

Assuming it gets finished, and [this blog](http://nasajsc.force.com/track/apex/sbm__sbx_emailviewonline?id=701d0000000yUI2AAM&mt=4200533936655&cmid=00vd000000IGfIKAA1) makes it seem more real.. Where will it take off from and land.

[

Comment: The landing site will change all the time. The only thing coming back to earth will be the [Orion Crew Module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_(spacecraft)#Crew_Module) which will most likely be landing in various spots in the the oceans. I am not 100% sure where it will be launched from, but most likely Cape Canaveral in Florida.

Comment: Thanks. Is it finalized that the Crew module will only land at sea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Launch will only be from LC-39B at Cape Caneveral, (except the very first demo flight on a Delta 4 Heavy, which will launch from LC-37 at the Cape) one of the two former Shuttle pads.  LC-39A will be turned over to SpaceX to use for their launches.

Landing will be in the ocean and only the Orion capsule itself will be recovered.  Not sure if Pacific or Atlantic, probably will depend on the mission and what is easiest to access from the incoming path.