# What was the typical perigee after a shuttle de-orbit burn?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, low-earth-orbit, reentry, space-shuttle, orbital-maneuver

What was the typical<sup>1</sup> (theoretical) perigee after a shuttle de-orbit burn?

I say 'theoretical' given that presumably the orbiter would already have undergone further deceleration before it reaches the perigee, but I'm just interested in the point they aimed for.  Logic would suggest the perigee did not need to be at ground level, just far enough into the atmosphere to create enough drag to ensure re-entry.

1. Did the target perigee change per mission or orbit?

Comment: See http://space.stackexchange.com/a/12014/25